# How to chmod the folder to make it writable for the server in php

Tags: php, permissions, chmod

How to  chmod the folder to make it writable for the server in php ?

I am using this function chomd as following

```
chmod("/images/original", 0750);
```

but still don't have the permission to write file . why ?

Comment: Who are you trying to write as ? Also who is the owner of the file ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the user your webserver runs on has no write access then it most likely is not the owner of the file, and therefore it cannot change permissions either.

To allow write access on the file for your webserver process either change the ownership (`chown`) or allow sufficient write permissions (`chmod`) on a shell.

Answer (score -3):

try

```
chmod("/images/original", 0777);
```

Comment: Don't give writing permissions to everyone on the server.

Comment: even if it's inside protected folder?