# php can't chmod folder

Tags: php, chmod, folder-permissions

I am trying to give 777 permissions to a folder on my hosting.
I use the following command: `chmod("./test",0777);`

I know it doesn't work because I execute a script which changes a file in the directory.
If I give the permissions manually (in the FTP) it works.
Why doesn't the chmod work?

Comment: Is the script in the same directory as `test`?

Comment: when running this from php, the user is usually 'apache'. This user doesn't have access to do many things, for security reasons.

Comment: nope, should be in the same directory? Aris, I can chmod files but not folder? different security rule for folders and files?

Comment: Have you tried without the `./` and just `chmod("test",0777);` and where are you executing from?

Comment: @Ron Aris got it right, it's a permission problem of the user running the command

Comment: to be honest I used `../test` because the folder is one step above... just wrote it this way so it will be easier

Comment: [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9432990/how-to-chmod-the-folder-to-make-it-writable-for-the-server-in-php) post... also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5019194/chmod-777-in-php).

Comment: can I let the php use different user or something similar?

Comment: have you tried different combinations, such as `chmod("/test",0777);` and my other suggestion?